# elixir guardian get current user in model

Tags: authentication, elixir, phoenix-framework

I can't get current logged in user in my model. There are many things which I wanna do with that. e.g when a user creates a blog post, I want to associate with that user. User has many blog posts. There are many scenarios in which I need current user.
  One solution I can think of is to add a virtual field to all of my schemas after authentication assign current user to that virtual field. But I dont wanna repeat to add that virtual field to all of my models.

Note: this question has been asked before and someone tried to send a conn object to model which is discourged.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Create service modules which have function(s) that accept all the required data included current user and do the required transformations, don't polute the schemas.

Comment: @JustMichael I have generic controllers, generic models, I dont repeat common code. But using this approach I have to write many services and call differnet services from my common controller, that will be complex. what do you think

Comment: Can you provide a code example of (a) how/where you're creating the data you need the user for, and (b) what you'd like to see instead? I have apps with user-associated models and I don't have to do anything in the model to build the associations (and in the rare places I do, I just pass in the user).

Comment: @DaveNewton I have the current user resource in conn object, which is of course not accessible in model. and I dont wanna send that user from my controller every time. I want this to be accessible in model.

Comment: I'm asking *why* you want it to be directly accessible in the model. It's not part of the model aside from the association, and that association is generally created outside of the model, which makes sense to me. So far it sounds like you'd rather have convenience than clear separation of concerns, which seems like a path to unhappiness.

Comment: +1 for @DaveNewton, I also faced a similar use case in my project and its more "Elixir-way" if the Model (Although I am using Context in Phx1.3) is unaware of the conn object at all. I ended up with sending them as param to the Model from the Controller layer after retrieving the user ID from the conn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at a simple tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@andreichernykh/phoenix-simple-authentication-authorization-in-step-by-step-tutorial-form-dc93ea350153), also [this](https://medium.com/@Stephanbv/elixir-phoenix-lets-code-authentication-todo-application-part-1-599ee94cd04d?utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=ZEEF&utm_source=https%3A%2F%2Ftech-craftsmanship.zeef.com%2Froberthopman) one is pretty nice.